# ExtJs click event in View

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to know on click of a view, which ExtJS control was clicked. Do i need to subscribe to click on    all the controls or is there a way I can subscribe to the root element and get actual ExtJS control clicked? I am able to find DOM elements but what i want is ExtJS control. 
I am using latest version ExtJs 5 and i want to listen to click on any element of a view which could be a Panel, Grid, Textarea etc. I am using a single event handler at the top level dom element. My code looks like follows:

```
    listeners: {
        click: {
            element: "el",
            fn: function fn(e,t) {
                var domComp = Ext.get(t);
                var xComp;
                var currentNode = t;
                while(true) {
                     var compID = currentNode.parentNode.id;
                     xComp = Ext.ComponentManager.get(compID);
                     if(xComp) break;
                     currentNode = currentNode.parentNode;
                }
                //Do something on xComp
           }
       }
   }
```

I have been partially able to achieve this. But still the problem that I have is that I don't want the click handler for the actual control to be invoked? Just the handler I have written above should be invoked. For ex: if a checkbox is clicked, i don't want it to get checked but instead my above handler is invoked and i know that this checkbox was clicked? Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for posting duplicate. This link seems to work for me as of now. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203872/ext-js-on-click-event)

Comment: Oops I think I was wrong. As per the documentation, it says Ext.get returns Dom element and not Ext Component. I need to find Ext Component. Any help please?

Comment: Which Ext version and what exactly is "control" to listen clicks on?